# Avoid creating HandlerThread and context leak

Tags: java, android, multithreading

#### Problem

I have an expensive image processing operation that has to be done in background. The processed image will be displayed in UI thread.

#### Current solution

```java
public class ImshowFragment extends Fragment {
    // Handler to this thread
    private final Handler handler = new ImshowHandler(this);

    // Lazy processing thread
    private static HandlerThread improcThread;

    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (improcThread == null) {    // Don't create if it's there
            improcThread = new HandlerThread("improc");
            improcThread.start();
        }

        // Send bitmap to process
        Handler improcHandler = new Handler(improcThread.getLooper());
        Runnable improcRun = new ImprocRunnable(handler, bitmap);
        improcHandler.post(improcRun);
    }

    private static class ImshowHandler extends Handler {

        private final WeakReference<HeaderFragment> imshowFragmentWk;

        public ImshowHandler(ImshowFragment imshowFragment) {
            imshowFragmentWk = new WeakReference<>(imshowFragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            ImshowFragment imshowFragment = imshowFragmentWk.get();
            if (imshowFragment != null)
                // Receive processed bitmap
                imshowFragment.show((Bitmap) msg.getData());
        }
    }

    private static class ImprocRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final Handler mUIHandler;
        private final Bitmap mBitmap;

        public ImprocRunnable(Handler uiHandler, Bitmap bitmap) {
            this.mUIHandler = uiHandler;
            this.mBitmap    = bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Process...

            // Send back to UI
            msg.setData(bitmap);
            mUIHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

The processing thread `improcThread` is created only once. When the device rotates, it's activity is destroyed, as well as the `ImshowFragment`, which makes this line invalid:

```java
Runnable improcRun = new ImprocRunnable(handler, bitmap);
```

as it only sends to the destroyed activity.

#### Question

How can I send the processed bitmap to any current `ImshowFragment`?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities:

1.) Does the HandlerThread have to be static or can it be part of ImshowFragment?  Perhaps you can create the HandlerThread in the onCreateView() of the Fragment.  That should get called when the fragment gets recreated after the device rotates.

2.) If it needs to be static, consider moving it outside of the Fragment into a static class.  Although it would be better to avoid static classes if possible.